# Tracking sales/conversions in Woocommerce using Google Analytics

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce, google-analytics

I need to be able to track conversions/orders in Woocommerce and have tried every free plugin available and none have worked or seem to be able to track sales correctly.

Has anyone found a free plugin that actually shows ecommerce transactions in Google Analytics or perhaps uses an alternative approach such as Google Tag Manager or Conversion code on the checkout success page.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the official WooCommerce Google Analytics plugin, it has been developed by WooCommerce, so that's always nice.

There is a [free version](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-google-analytics/) and a [paid version](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-google-analytics-pro/).  Sometimes you get what you pay for, I think the paid version is worth it but I guess it depends on your needs.

Here is a [comparison chart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-google-analytics-pro-vs-free/) of the different features of paid vs free.

Comment: Tried this plugin yesterday, ecomm switched on in GA. Will not track any sales with traffic/ecommerce section or the Conversions section either. Just doesn't do it for me at all. Normal stats show fine but no ecommerce details showing in the plugin for me